# SendAsync() returns no data

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I made a form in Blazor WebApplication (Client). When submited, all data gets posted to a Server, where it gets processed. The server then sends a response to the client whether the operation was successful or not, but the SendAsync() method does not return any response from the server.

```
string json = <Serialized Object>;

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://<server_address>");
request.Content = new StringContent(json);
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
    bool isSuccessCode = response.IsSuccessStatusCode; // false

    string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine(responseStr); // prints empty string

    if (responseStr == "Success")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The response variable does not contain any useful data, but only has default values in it (0s and nulls) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy3JQ.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAtzy.png)

When I tried the same code(methods) with the same config (except CORS) in a console app, it worked without any problems and I got the desired response from the server.

```
// This worked
internal static async Task<string> Post(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    request.Content = new StringContent(data);

    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var result = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // proper response was returned
}
```

[Codedump to my code](https://www.codedump.xyz/less/ZJ1zgqnkBR1o6QaQ)

Link to a GitHub project showing my issue: https://github.com/SjamesE/SendAsync-BugReport/

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP request log in your browser's developer tools? In Chrome/Firefox they open with F12 and there should be a "Network" tab. I suspect you will see that the `OPTIONS` request to the server endpoint failed due to CORS. This should also be visible in the browser console.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride After checking the Network tab, I can confirm that I get Status 200 OK, and I can see that the response is "Success". Referrer Policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', Sec-Fetch-Mode: 'no-cors', Sec-Fetch-Site: 'cross-site'

Comment: So you get 200 for both the OPTIONS request (a.k.a. pre-flight request) and your POST request?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BE7dHdy

Comment: There is only one request

Comment: That's very weird indeed...

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. You could try to drop the `ConfigureAwait(false)` or change it to `true`. Maybe drop the `await` and do `.Result` just for testing. But those are long shots. You might be looking at a Blazor bug here. Could be that responses for requests with `BrowserRequestMode.NoCors` are not handled correctly? Consider opening an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Afeature-components

Comment: Have you tried configuring CORS on the server and dropping `BrowserRequestMode.NoCors`?

Comment: I made a new project to show my problem. Maybe I am not using async methods correctly. That's the only lead I have left. And no, I sadly can not configure CORS on the server. Here is the codedump: [link](https://www.codedump.xyz/less/ZJ1zgqnkBR1o6QaQ)

Comment: HttpClient is definitely misused - it's meant to be reused, not disposed. It's unclear whether the question is about Blazor WASM or Blazor Server, because in Blazor WASM the *client* is actually the browser. There's a very good reason all tutorials and samples inject HttpClient instead of creating it

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is another critical bug in Blazor WASM - there's only one thread, provided by the browser. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't mean you avoid deadlocks, it means the browser thread no loger waits of the operation to complete. If the application fails to wait for the response, the browser has no reason to do so either

Comment: BTW most of this code could be replaced with eg `var response=Http.PostAsJsonAsync(url,thatObject);` where Http is the HttpClient instance injected with `@inject HttpClient Http`. All this is described in [Call a web API from ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this doesn't fix it. I have now used the injected Http client, but I get the exact same response. I can not use PostAsJsonAsync because I have to use nocors first. So I create a request and then SendAsync(). And just like before, I do not get anything from that method and removing ConfigureAwait(false) didn't help either. I will open an issue on this.

Comment: @AlaNdala it works, I and *every* Blazor WASM developer works that way. What wasn't fixed? What does your code look like *now*? You're arguing that Blazor WASM itself doesn't work at all for anyone - without HttpClient, Single Page Applications are useless. If that was the case, every Blazor WASM developer would have noticed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://github.com/SjamesE/SendAsync-BugReport

Comment: This will fail due to CORS restrictions. That's what the very first comment talks about. CORS policies are set by the server, not scripts, whether written in JavaScript or WASM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos dude I an using NoCors. What are you talking about?? My current request looks exactly like the one on github

Comment: Which doesn't have any CORS settings. What you posted is just a *standalone client* project. There's no server project. No `web.config`, or whatever NGINX may be using

Comment: I  aM uSiNg NoCors !!!!!!!!! `request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);`

Comment: that's not [how CORS works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). It's not something that the browser *script* can alter. If that were the case, it would be entirely useless. The script's source *server* tells the browser what CORS policies should apply, ie which URLs the script can call. Without any policies, a script can only call its origin, ie source server. No matter how you create HttpClient, what headers you set on the HTTP request, the *browser* will refuse to send it if it violates the policies.

Comment: What you posted is a standalone SPA, without any server that would set CORS policies that allow calling `https://ptsv3.com`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this post: You can NOT have no-cors reqests on the Blazor WebAssembly App. When using the following line, you can send a request, but the response will not be returned to your code.

```
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
```

If you still need to use the response from those requests, you need to switch to a Blazor Server App, or to create a host and route your requests through it.